# avoid a single figure on one page with lots of empty space

Tags: spacing, floats

This script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}                                                                                                                                                                                
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  }\\                                                                                                                                                                                           
  \subfloat[]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  }
\end{figure}
\lipsum[6-10]
\end{document}
```

produces the output:

[image: ![enter image description here]

There is a lot of empty space around the figure that could be economically filled with text. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I think increasing the `\floatpagefraction` (default=`0.5`) should do: `\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.8}`...

Comment: Have a look at this question: [avoid that figure gets its own page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68516), especially the last answer, for more information.

Comment: David showed it. You have to understand how the floats are placed. There is real "must read" about [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/11604). The you can fill the entire page with text without leaving a free space. Now the question is: why the hell? You  spend the same number of pages and the text is worse distributed, and the figure is left in a less prominent place. Not an improvement, IMHO.

Comment: @Fran in the example it stays at three pages but it's likely to be more compact in other documents, if there had been a few more lines of text then this example would already have gone from 4 to 3 pages by forcing a top float here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Of course. I was referring to this specific MWE. It is clear that in another document this can help to save trees, and depending of how big is the figure, even in a elegant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}                                                                                                                                                                                
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \subfloat[]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  }\\                                                                                                                                                                                           
  \subfloat[]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  }
\end{figure}
\lipsum[6-10]
\end{document}
```